# Чтение чисел со стандартного потока, отбрасывая мусор

Tags: c++

Не могу разобраться как ограничить чтение с std, чтобы в функцию заносились чисто числовые значения, игнорируя буквы и прочий мусор.

```
Figure *ptr = new Rhombus(std::cin);

Rhombus::Rhombus(double len1, double len2) : len1(len1), len2(len2) {
    cout << "Rhombus created:" << endl;
    this->Print();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Конструктор Rhombus принимает два параметра типа `double` , а не поток. Чтобы считать два значения из потока ввода, проще всего считать их в переменные, например так:

```
double a,b;
std::cin >> a;
std::cin >> b;

Figure* ptr = new Rhombus(a,b);
```